# ¿Cómo hacer un evento que se repita al principio de cada mes en Java?

Tags: java, timer

Tengo que hacer un método en Java que me permita, de manera automática, reiniciar al principio de cada mes el valor de una variable (un importe). Estuve haciendo esto con `Timer` y `TimerTask`:

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        var = 0;
    }
};
timer.schedule(task, delay, period);
```

El problema es que el parámetro `period` es una cantidad exacta en tiempo, yo no le quiero indicar dentro de cuanto tiempo se debe ejecutar la tarea, sino que quiero indicar en qué momento específico se va ejecutar (al inicio de cada mes).

Comment: revisa el siguiente enlace https://www.journaldev.com/2800/java-8-date-localdate-localdatetime-instant

Comment: Busca información de ScheduledTask por google y encontrarás la solución 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021895/schedule-monthly-task-using-scheduledexecutorservice

Comment: Échale un vistazo a la librería **Quartz**.

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo uso de las clases `Timer` y `TimerTask` puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int dayOfMonth = LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth();
        if (dayOfMonth == 1) {
            // TODO llamar servicio para actualizar
        }
    }
};

LocalDateTime of = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), LocalTime.of(7, 0));
Date from = Date.from(of.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, from, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
```

En este caso estoy indicando que programe la tarea a las 7:00 hrs del día de mañana y que se ejecute cada día a la misma hora.

Una vez que inicie la tarea programada verifico si es el día 1 del mes y en caso de que este sea verdadero mando a llamar al servicio encargado de realizar la tarea.

Cabe mencionar que si estas utilizando *Spring* puedes hacer uso de la anotación `@Scheduled(cron=". . .")` o utilizar una librería como `Quartz` que te permite añadir muchas más opciones.

### Referencias

- [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)
- [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)
- [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)
- [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma de hacerlo, es con las clase Quartz, como indica Angel mas arriba, dentro de las posibilidades que tienes puede usar Cron Expression ,

esta son las librerías que necesitarías

```
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
```